# Is this sentence (The teacher gives you conversation starters...) gramatically correct? Nobody got it when I said it

Tags: grammaticality, spoken-english

I'm starting a course and our teacher gives us cards with a bit of information about each student in the class, maybe to mingle the group.  Then I said the following to explain a friend what was going on:

> *"The teacher gives you conversation starters to mingle with people you
>   don't know but whom you are going to spend some time with".*

Is that phrase grammatically correct?  It seems to me that it does, but no body understand me, and this time I'm sure it was not caused by my pronunciation.

Comment: Hi Ruben - what did the people you told this to say that made you think they didn't understand you?

Comment: Hi @ColleenV, They told me explicity  they can't understand me.  One of them was a native speaker I just texted.  If the sentence is correct and clear for you, maybe the context was missing for them.

Comment: I understood it perfectly (as a native speaker). Strictly speaking the conversation starters do not themselves mingle with people (it is you that does) and so there's an ambiguity which comes close to making the sentence fail, but only just if so. As Peter says, it may be rather involved.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: No, there's no ambiguity. Precisely because *conversation starters do not themselves mingle with people*, as you point out. As a rule, native speakers neither notice nor care about such "hypothetical" ambiguities. Especially in *English*, which over time has tended to do away with syntactic / morphological elements whose only purpose is to comply with "disambiguating" rules of grammar. Anglophones usually let the ***semantics of the context*** do the heavy lifting of disambiguation. That's nearly always enough, and it allows use of "simpler" constructions overall.

Comment: ...that's to say, as a rule, wherever ***to...*** means ***in order to...*** *(**for the purpose of...**)* it's probably fine to just use the shorter form unless the context (the containing sentence) is so long and complex the relation between the syntactic elements is potentially unclear. For native speakers, that *doesn't* apply to the cited example here. Bear in mind that ordinarily, native Anglophones have no reason to make their choice of phrasing easier for non-native speakers to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is understandable, but thinking like an English student, maybe

> The teacher **gave us** conversation starters **so we can** mingle with **the other students we** don't know but **with** whom **we** are going to spend some time.

might work better since it is more literal and less is assumed.   It could also be the length of your sentence is throwing them off.